# How to specify the people query for the people component?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

What do I need to do to filter the responses for the people graph call? For example I need to be able to only return people (and not conference rooms) 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$filter=personType/class eq 'Person' and personType/subclass eq 'OrganizationUser'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the `mgt-people` component in the Microsoft Graph Toolkit? The component does not support customizing the query but I encourage you to create a feature request to add that support

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out `mgt-get`, which allows you to specify in greater detail the data you would like to have returned from Graph. Check out the resource attribute/property on the mgt-get component at https://mgt.dev/?path=/docs/components-mgt-get--get-email